# Created Image of Canvas haven't get appended to html container

Tags: jquery, canvas, todataurl

I have a canvas. Now i want to make an image of the canvas. This function i already developed. I've got an image with the right src-attribute. But if i want to append this image-element to the html-container, it doesn't works. Nothing happens.

I don't know why. The html-container is available, the image is correct.

Here is some code:

Function to create the picture

```
function createPicture(canvas, container){
    
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        format: 'jpeg',
    });
    
    let image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute("src", dataURL);

    container.append(image);
}
```

Calling this function

```
createPicture(canvas, $("#test"));
```

Image in the console:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, see my sample below

```js
function createPicture(canvas, container){
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
        left: 0, top: 0,
        format: 'jpeg',
    });
    
    let image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute("src", dataURL);
    container.append(image);
}

let co = document.getElementById("container")
let ca = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = ca.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(10, 10, 80, 60);
ctx.arc(50, 50, 30, 0, 4);
ctx.stroke();

createPicture(ca, co)
```

```css
canvas { 
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
div { 
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Only thing I could think of is you are doing something on your canvas after you call the createPicture an expecting it to be there, if you still run into problems I would recommend you to create a code snippet reproducing your problem and post it here

---

Check on your dev console, make sure you see the image element:
[image]
If you don't see it then the problem must be the container

Comment: Hey,

thanks for your answer. I tryed it again and found the problem why it doesn't works. The Problem was that the HTML-Container was placed in the Canvas-Container. After placing it outside of the Canvas-Container it works fine.